# How to implement "header" base class that accesses same table but excludes some data

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I've got an existing table - for example

```
create table Users (
  Id Int,
  UserId varchar(10),
  FirstName nvarchar(30),
  MiddleName nvarchar(30),
  LastName nvarchar(30),
  BirthDate datetime,
  ProfilePicture varbinary(max),
  HeaderPicture varbinary(max)
);
```

Since `ProfilePicture` and `HeaderPicture` are large, I would not like to retrieve them if they are not needed. In the name of readability and preventing NullReferenceExceptions, I'd like to use two different classes - one with only "header" information, and one with the full information.

Here's about what I was thinking:

```
[Table("Users")]
public class UserHeader
{
    [Key, Display(AutoGenerateField = false)]
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(10)]
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(30)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [StringLength(30)]
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(30)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
}

public class User : UserHeader
{
    public byte[] ProfilePicture { get; set; }
    public byte[] HeaderPicture { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to use this, I get an error that there is no discriminator column in my table. If I add `HasNoDiscriminator()` to the modelbuilder, I get a different error:

> The entity type 'IncidentHeader' is part of a hierarchy, but does not have a discriminator property configured

I don't want a discriminator - every row should be retrievable as either a User and UserHeader, depending on which DBSet is used to access it.

Is there any way to achieve this kind of setup with EntityFramework Core?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following approach

```
public class UserHeader
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public byte[] ProfilePicture { get; set; }
    public byte[] HeaderPicture { get; set; }
}
```

Map both classes to a single table with the fluent interface.

```
public class DB : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<UserHeader> UserHeaders { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserHeader>(uh =>
        {
            uh.ToTable("Users");

            uh.HasOne(uh => uh.User).WithOne()
                .HasForeignKey<User>(u => u.Id);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>(user =>
        {
            user.ToTable("Users");
        });
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(
            ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Database"].ConnectionString);
    }
}
```

See documentation: [Table Splitting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/table-splitting)

Comment: Thanks.. I think I'm likely to do the inverse - where a User contains a UserHeader, but assuming there's no way to do the inheritance method, this seems like a good solution.